# How to convert nvarchar column to datetime type in MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a nvarchar(50) column named "created_time" in MS SQL with the following string format

**Thu Mar 03 09:43:25 +0000 2016**

How do I convert it into a datetime type or select "created_time" as a datetime column?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Christina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ignore the time zone, you can readily use `convert()`:

```
select convert(datetime,
               left(stuff(stuff(created_time, 1, 4, ''), 8, 0, right(created_time, 4) + ' '), 20),
               100)
```

Actually, the intention here is to convert the string to the format "MMM DD YYYY HH:MI:SS", which is default format so `cast()` could also be used.